# Discord.py, how to kick a member 0.16.2 or lower

Tags: python, python-3.5, discord.py

(UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED) You can use the following code that I made to make a kick command:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if author.server_permissions.kick_members:
        await bot.kick(user)
        await bot.say("{} has been kicked!".format(user.name))
    else:
        await bot.say("You do **NOT** have permission to run this command!")
```

Big thanks to [abccd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622817/abccd) for reminding me to put `await` in front of `bot.kick(user)`.

Comment: Which version of `discord.py` are you using? The rewrite version? Or something else?

Comment: Not sure, but most likely `bot.kick(user)` need to be awaited. And please ask only one question at a time

Comment: Did you [give your bot permission](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206029707-How-do-I-set-up-Permissions-) to kick members on your server?

Comment: If that doesn't work then try `user.kick()`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have edited my question so it does not become very confusing. Again, sorry for the confusion.